# NameError (uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Picture): i am getting this error onclick on send it to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

NameError (uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Picture):
 i am getting this error should i write pictures controller .
i am unable to upload the image using ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

In config.js

In that change the path of browser upload path give custom path there define own method. There you can write your own like

```
def upload_image
      @func_num = params["CKEditorFuncNum"]
      @ck_editor = params["CKEditor"]
      if params.include?(:upload)
      data = params[:upload]
        @image = Upload.create(:image => data) if data.present?
      end
      render :layout => false
    end\
```

coresponding view in html

```
- if @image
  = image_tag @image.image.url
  :javascript
    CKEditorFuncNum = #{@func_num};
    function SetUrl( fileUrl )
    {
      window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(CKEditorFuncNum, fileUrl);
    }
    SetUrl("#{ @image.image.url }");
```

note : only if you are using paperclip for upload image.